# Proving that there exists a solution for the equation: $\exp({x^2-1})=x+2$ in the interval $(1,3)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Prove that there exists a solution for the equation $\exp({x^2-1})=x+2$ in the interval $(1,3)$.

Can someone tell me, if I proved this correctly? I first defined a function $f(x):= \exp(x^2-1)-x-2$. Then I looked for the solution for $x=1$ and $x=3$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(1)&=\exp(1^2-1)-1-2=1-1-2=-2 &<0\\
f(3)&=\exp(3^2-1)-3-2=\exp(8)-3-2&>0
\end{aligned}
$$
because $e^8>2^8=256$ and $256-5>0$. Therefore because of the intermediate value theorem (and $\exp$ is continuous) we know that there exists a $x\in(1,3)$ with $f(x)=0$ which is equal to
$$
f(x)=0 \Longleftrightarrow \exp(x^2-1)=x+2. 
$$

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: @Astyx My main concern here is that the interval is not a compact interval. Instead it is an open one. Is that not an issue here (and if not could you please explain why)?

Comment: The theorem yields a solution in $[1,3]$. But you know $1$ and $3$ are not solutions already. So where does the solution have to be?

Comment: Okay I got it, that was exactly what I was thinking. Because we already know that the two endpoints are not solutions, the solution has to be somewhere in the open interval. Thanks!

Comment: It looks good except for the definition of $f$. You shouldn't write "=0” at the end.